# Azure Network Security Groups - Inbound allow multiple IPs to access specific port

Tags: azure, azure-security, network-security-groups

I have made a network security group in Azure in order to block external connections to certain endpoints. I have added several rules to enforce this.

Currently the rules allow one white-listed IP To access all ports and another white-listed Port to access only two specific ports. My rules are as follows:

---

- Source: IP Addresses
- Source IP address range: XX.XXX.XXX.XX
- Source port range: *
- Destination: *
- Destination port range: *
- Protocol: Any
- Action Allow
- Priority: 1000
- Name: Allow-All

  ---
- Source: IP Addresses
- Source IP address range: YY.YYY.YY.YY
- Source port range: *
- Destination: *
- Destination port range: 1234
- Protocol: Any
- Action Allow
- Priority: 200
- Name: Allow-Cus1-1234

  ---
- Source: IP Addresses
- Source IP address range: YY.YYY.YY.YY
- Source port range: *
- Destination: *
- Destination port range: 4321
- Protocol: Any
- Action Allow
- Priority: 199
- Name: Allow-Cus1-4321

  ---

This works as expected and we are able to access our all our endpoints and the user of the other IP is able to access the two ports (1234 and 4321 that they have access to). However the problem arises when I want to open these two ports to additional other IP addresses. I added an additional two rules as below:

---

- Source: IP Addresses
- Source IP address range: ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ
- Source port range: *
- Destination: *
- Destination port range: 1234
- Protocol: Any
- Action Allow
- Priority: 198
- Name: Allow-Cus2-1234

  ---
- Source: IP Addresses
- Source IP address range: ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ
- Source port range: *
- Destination: *
- Destination port range: 4321
- Protocol: Any
- Action Allow
- Priority: 197
- Name: Allow-Cus2-4321

  ---

I thought this would work but it seems not to. So does anyone know if I have missed a step or forgotten to add any important information to the rules? My theory is somehow the similar rules are conflicting with each other.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add multiple IPs to the same inbound rule in a network security group?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what is happening? Is ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ not able to access 1234 and 4321 or are the other IP addresses now blocked?

Comment: Your configuration is right, do you check ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ is your customer right IP address? Also, you should ensure port 1243 and 4321 is listening.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly has been asked in above question but as per my understanding, here is what I know.

So we can add Source and destination port/IP using comma separated like following e.g.

Source: IP Addresses

**Source IP address range: ZZ.ZZZ.ZZ.ZZ,YY.YYY.YY.YY**

Source port range: *

Destination: *

**Destination port range: 4321,4562,7589**

Protocol: Any

Action Allow

Priority: 197

Name: Allow-Cus2-4321